# Fastest possible hash function / lookup for primitive key

Tags: performance, hash, hashmap, hashtable

My application needs to do a lookup in a data set potentially several million times per second. (HPC related)

It is a very specific use case where the following is true:

- The data set has a fixed set of entries. It never shrinks, nor grows.
- The key is a primitive (a 2-byte int)
- There are never any duplicate keys (duh!)
- There's never more than 200-300 entries in the data set.
- The keys will tend to cluster in the range 0 to 1000 rather than being distributed evenly over -32,768 thru 32,767.

What would be the fastest possible hash function for this case ?

I know at least one:

```
hashValue = key % DATASET_FIXED_SIZE;  // Java syntax for modulo
```

but I believe the distribution of that function is sub-optimal in my case.

So what - with the above "knowns" - is the fastest possible hash function. I'm a newbie at math so I wouldn't know if there's such a thing as a [minimal perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function) for the specific use case. If there is then let me know. :-)

NB: As the data set is fixed in size I only care about lookup performance.

EDIT:  I don't care much about setup time. I'm perfectly willing to trade setup time for that extra little piece of lookup performance. This means that hash table approaches may not even be the best approach, e.g. use brute force array scan if n is less than say 10, use binary search if 10 < n < 50 and use some hash table approach is n > 50 (n is number of pairs, 0 and 50 are just some numbers I came up with to make the point clear)

Further info:  Use case is for in-memory data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use the Java HashMap, the best hashCode() realization I can think of is the following:

```
public class Sample
{
    private static int CLASS_ID = 0; 
    private final int id;

    public Sample()
    {
        CLASS_ID++;
        id = CLASS_ID;
    }

    // other constructors following the same pattern as in the default constructor

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return id;
    }

}
```

All constructors of sample will ensure that CLASS_ID is incremented and then assigned to the id field. This hashCode() function will always return a unique value for every instance which can avoid two instances being placed inside one bucket in the hash map - assuming the hash map has enough buckets. This increases the performance but at the cost of memory.

Furthermore, this implementation has two downfalls though:

1: If more instances are created than the size of an interger can hold, this realization will not work. However, this should not be the case if you intend to use only 200 to 300 instances.

2: The 'greatest' downfall though is using CLASS_ID as a (global state) static variable. Static variables will stay in memory for the entire run-time of the programm.

Ulimatly, it is your discion as the programmer to wager the costs and trade-offs of a certain implementation.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in your case the key, `Sample`, is an object, not a primitive as in my case. Strictly speaking I need a fast efficient hash function where the result is the index into an array and the key is a `short` (to stay in Java terminology)

Comment: short is a primitive data type. Primitive data types cannot be used as keys - only their respective wrapper classes can; those wrapper already have hashCodes() defined though. Are you asking for a hash function that will accept any type T and return a hash? Are we misreading each other?

Comment: The question is not about Java per se. It is more fundamental. Even in Java my key does not have to be wrapped in an object unless I insist on using the standard JDK implementation of HashMap. But there are tons of other implementations as well (fastutils, Trove, Koloboke, HPPC, etc) that allows the key to be a primitive. I could use one of those but I was thinking that my use case is so restrictive that I can do better. But perhaps there isn't. Don't know enough about math to say. FastUtils and Koloboke seem to both both use a MurMur3 hash function.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I could use one of those great libraries but I was hoping there would be an even simpler and faster solution because I can narrow down my use case to something quite restrictive. Those libraries have to cater as well for the more generalized cases.

Comment: Oh I assumed we were speaking in Java terms because of the comment in your code "Java syntax for modulo". Misunderstanding from my side then. In that case the least answer I can give you is not to use modulo because it devides - deviding is a relativly slow operation compared to other arithmatic operations.

Answer (score 0):

Koloboke doesn't use Murmur; even for linear hashing, it uses a bit simplier mixing: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Koloboke/blob/344089c9fc7c2b53ba7d1299eb29214206e1ab1d/lib/impl/src/main/javaTemplates/net/openhft/koloboke/collect/impl/hash/LHash.java#L34

In you case I would suggest make a direct lookup table for keys in 0-1000 range (not hash), and hash rest values using a linear hash table multiplying by a random constant (you can try several for each specific case and see which results to less collisions, or just stick with a value like `-1640531527`.

```
int index = key * random & (rest_table_size_power_of_2 - 1);
```